# Flattening a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm new to Python and would appreciate if someone could please help on this:

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| Celebrity1 | Celebrity2 | Celebrity3 | Votes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brad Pitt | Angelina Jolie | - | 49 |
| Will Smith | Chris Rock | Justin Bieber | 55 |

I want to "flatten" this database so it looks like this:

| Celebrity | Votes |
| --- | --- |
| Brad Pitt | 49 |
| Angelina Jolie | 49 |
| Will Smith | 55 |
| Chris Rock | 55 |
| Justin Bieber | 55 |

How can I do this in Python?

```
#here is the code for the initial dataframe

data = {'Celebrity1': ['Brad Pitt','Will Smith'], 'Celebrity2': ['Angelina Jolie', 'Chris Rock'],'Celebrity3': [None,'Justin Bieber'],'Votes': [49,55]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `wide_to_long`:

```
out = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames='Celebrity', i='index', j='j')
       .dropna().sort_values(by='Votes').reset_index(drop=True))
```

Another option is to use `set_index` + `stack`:

```
df = df.set_index('Votes').stack().droplevel(-1).reset_index(name='Celebrity')[['Celebrity','Votes']]
```

Output:

```
        Celebrity  Votes
0       Brad Pitt     49
1  Angelina Jolie     49
2      Will Smith     55
3      Chris Rock     55
4   Justin Bieber     55
```